# VBA Help shorten code, introduce routines?

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I have a generic bit of code I am using to hide rows for a excel document I am creating, I will be using this code a lot in this spreadsheet and have got to the point where I have an error 'Procedure too large'.
The code in question is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
''''''''General Selection statement'''''''
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F7"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is = "-": Rows("8:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is = "No": Rows("8:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "Yes": Rows("8:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
End If
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is = "Other": Rows("9:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is <> "Other": Rows("9:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
End If
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C11"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is = "-": Rows("12:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is = "Yes": Rows("12:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "No": Rows("12:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Will it be possible to create a sub routine and then call this when required?
The selected cells will change but the ranges will stay the same, I hope that makes sense?
I'm new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to repeat code, similar code should be put either into a loop or into sub routines that you can call with the desired parameter, so re-use the same sub routine with different parameters. • Note that `Range(Target.Address)` is exatcly the same as writing just `Target`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to repeat code, similar code should be put either into a loop or into sub routines that you can call with the desired parameter, so re-use the same sub routine with different parameters.

Note that `Range(Target.Address)` is exatcly the same as writing just `Target`.

For example the following into a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ToggleMode
    tmYesNo
    tmOther
End Enum

Public Sub ToggleRows(ByVal Mode As ToggleMode, ByVal CheckRange As Range, ByVal Target As Range, ByVal RowsAddress As String)

    If Not Application.Intersect(CheckRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim ToggleRange As Range
        Set ToggleRange = Target.Parent.Rows(RowsAddress).EntireRow

        If Mode = tmYesNo Then
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "-", "Yes": ToggleRange.Hidden = True
                Case "No":       ToggleRange.Hidden = False
            End Select

        ElseIf Mode = tmOther Then
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case Is = "Other":  ToggleRange.Hidden = False
                Case Is <> "Other": ToggleRange.Hidden = True
            End Select

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

And the following in your worksheet code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub  'exit if target is a range and not a single cell.

    ToggleRows tmYesNo, Me.Range("F7"), Target, "8:20"
    ToggleRows tmOther, Me.Range("B8"), Target, "9:10"
    ToggleRows tmYesNo, Me.Range("C11"), Target, "12:1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Solid answer, a good rewrite. Only question is why is `ToggleRows` a function when it doesn't return a value? A think a `Sub` would be clearer.

Comment: @RyanWildry Meeh, because coffee is out and I didn't pay attention ^^. Of course it has to be a procedure.

Comment: No worries. Great answer, +1.